# MATLAB: why transpose single dimension array

Tags: matlab, vbscript, transpose

I have the following Matlab code snippet that I'm having to translate to VBScript. However, I'm not understanding why the last line is even necessary.

```
clear i
for i = 1:numb_days
    doy(i) = floor(dt_daily(i) - datenum(2012,12,31,0,0,0));
end
doy = doy';
```

Looking over the rest of the code, this happens in a lot of other places where there are single dimension arrays (?) being transposed in place. I'm a newbie when it comes to both these languages, as well as posting a question on Stack, as I'm a sleuth when it comes to finding answers, just not in this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably to avoid `Matrix dimensions must agree` errors. Try `[1 2] - [1; 2]`.

Comment: I think you're right. Apparently, MATLAB treats single dimension arrays as matrices? Which means that the array can be vertical or horizontal, thus necessitating a transpose. Thanks for your insight

Comment: Exactly @javon27. The arrays in Matlab are for a lot more than just storing data. Think math. Matlab does stand for "Matrix Labratory" after all. For, example `[1 2]'*[1 2]`, `[1 2]*[1 2]'` and `[1 2].*[1 2]` are all different.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having to translate all this Matlab code, and don't have access to Matlab itself. So, I finally decided to ask on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All "arrays" in MATLAB have at least two dimensions, and can be treated as having any number of dimensions you wish. The transpose operator here is converting between a row (size `[1 N]` array) and a column (size `[N 1]` array). This can be significant when it comes to either concatenating the arrays, or performing other operations.

Conceptually, the dimension vector of a MATLAB array has as many trailing `1`s as is required to perform an operation. This means that you can index any MATLAB array with any number of subscripts, providing you don't exceed the bounds, like so:

```
x = magic(4); % 4-by-4 square matrix
x(2,3,1,1,1) % pick an element
```

One final note: the `'` operator is the complex-conjugate transpose CTRANSPOSE. The `.'` operator is the ordinary TRANSPOSE operator.